# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to select a bunch of patients with their unit and division and I want to group the result by unit name, but this code doesn't execute and gives the error as the topic of this question.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    Pat.PatName AS Name, 
    srvDiv.sgMType AS Perkhidmatan,
    Pat.PatMRank AS Pangkat, 
    Pat.PatMilitaryID AS [No# Tentera],
    unt.untName AS Unit,
    fct.pesStatusCode as StatusCode,
    fct.pesSignedDate AS SignedDate

FROM dbo.FactPES AS fct INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DimPatient AS Pat ON fct.pesPatID = Pat.PatID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.DimUnit AS unt ON fct.pesUnitID = unt.untID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.DimServiceDiv AS srvDiv ON fct.pesServiceDivID = srvDiv.sgID 
GROUP BY unt.untName
HAVING (deas.diDate BETWEEN  
    CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate, 102) 
AND 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, @ToDate, 102))
```

I assume it's because unt.UntName is in my left join so I can't use it outside the join maybe ? I'm a bit confused because when I put it like this it works:

```
GROUP BY unt.untName, Pat.PatName, srvDiv.sgMType, 
    Pat.PatMRank, Pat.PatMilitaryID, unt.untName, 
    fct.pesStatusCode, fct.pesSignedDate
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "I want to group the result by unit name" - I think you have failed to understand what `group by` does in SQL: it means that you will only return one row for each unique grouped value - so if you group by unit name, you will only get one row for each unit, **no matter how many patients belong to that unit**. What are you actually *trying* to do?

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't use `TOP (100) PERCENT`; it hurts even to read.

Second, your query contains no aggregate function, no `SUM` or `COUNT` for example.  When you say you want to "group by unit name", I suspect you may simply want the results sorted by unit name.  In that case, you want `ORDER BY` instead.  (The advice from other to study what `group by` does is well taken.)

Finally, you might not need those `CONVERT` functions at the end, depending on your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a `GROUP BY` - it should be present in the `SELECT` statement as a column. And if you do not want to contain it in a `GROUP BY` use it as an `AGGREGATE` column in `SELECT`.

So now in your case the second `GROUP BY` stated in your question will work.

Read this to understand more about [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)